# Requirejs what is the use of deps in shim configuration

Tags: javascript, requirejs

i read the **requirejs** document from here [api](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/',
    paths: {
        app: 'app/js',
        jquery: '',
    },
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: '$',
        },
        knockout: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'underscore'],
            exports: 'KnockOut'
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        a:{
            deps: ['x','b'],
            exports: 'a'
        }
    }
});
```

but i am not getting **deps** part of **shim**.
why should i use deps and does that mean these files(`x` and `b`) will auto load if i load only `a` or what else

```
    require(['a'], function(a){
    });
```

I tried but couldn't getting auto load `x` and `b`.
please can any one explain with example why and when should we use deps.
thanks.

Comment: with deps, it will make sure that `x` and `b` will get loaded before loading `a`. In short you have specified the exact order in which scripts would get loaded, instead of manually adding them as `<script>` tags in your index.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RequireJS loads modules that conform to the Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD). An AMD module must call a function named `define` provided by the AMD loader. The basic call is like this:

```
define(["a", "b", "c", ...], function (a, b, c, ...) {
});
```

The first argument is a list of the modules that the module being defined depends on. The 2nd argument is a factory function that builds the module being defined. RequireJS passes to it the modules that were listed in the dependencies. There are other ways to call `define` but the example above is typical.

That's all nice and well but what happens if you want to load a library produced by a third party but that is not an AMD module? The `shim` option allows telling RequireJS how to load those modules. For an AMD module, you specify dependencies in the array you pass to `define`, but for a non-AMD module you define a `shim` that contains a list of dependencies in the `deps` option. It contains the name of modules that must be loaded before the shimmed module is loaded. In your example, `x` and `b` must be loaded before `a`.